# How to come up with color palette for a game

Tags: color-theory, games, palette

I am trying to come up with a color palette for my game. The game is similar to Hearthstone (trading card game). I have broken down the requirement to 3 palettes ...
1. Palette for background elements.
2. Palette for main elements (that will be used in game interactions like cards, effects).
3. Palette for UI elements (menus/info for the player).

Googling different palettes gives me individual pallets for each element but how to come up with 3 palettes that are harmonious to each other?

Are there other factors that I should consider as well?

Thanks!